# Why does visual basic copy a last empty Column when exporting a DataGridView to Clipboard

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Thank you for looking at my problem. ^^
I have a small project with a "Copy to Clipboard" button which doesn't work as intended.
I want to copy all 11 Columns and all 10 Rows but it always adds a 12th empty Column, when I subtract a Column from `dgvRandom.ColumnCount` than the last Column which is supposed to have content is empty. (Picture to clarify - Green is my intention - Red is the actual state) https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvqpr.png
The code I'm referring to is this:

```
Private Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    For row As Integer = 0 To dgvRandom.RowCount - 1
        For col As Integer = 0 To dgvRandom.ColumnCount - 1
            sb.Append(dgvRandom(col, row).Value?.ToString)
            sb.Append(ControlChars.Tab)
        Next
        sb.Append(ControlChars.NewLine)
    Next

    Clipboard.SetDataObject(New DataObject(sb.ToString.Trim))
    MsgBox("Copied to Clipboard", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the final TAB before your line break.  To remove it, try changing

```
sb.Append(ControlChars.Tab)
```

to

```
If col<dgvRandom.ColumnCount - 1 then sb.Append(ControlChars.Tab)
```

or even

```
 If col<dgvRandom.ColumnCount - 1 then 
    sb.Append(ControlChars.Tab)  
 else
    sb.Append(ControlChars.NewLine)
 end if
```

and then delete the sb.Append(ControlChars.NewLine) after the loop

Comment: The first version worked perfectly fine. Thank you very much :)